# Get Binding Data Value AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

i implement data binding using AngularJS, but i how to get updated binding value?

```
<input type="text" ng-value="(harga * (dp/100)) | currency:'':0" ng-model="dp_hidden">
```

I get using this code :

```
<td><span id="value-dp" ng-bind="dp_hidden | currency:'':0"></span></td>
```

But it not work, the value not show.

Answer (score 0):

Is your entire HTML page under an Angular module? i.e. do you have one of the lines
`<html ng-app="yourAngularModule">` or `<body ng-app-"yourAngularModule">` 
in your page?

You'll need it for the page to compile properly.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to bind an initial value to the span with the text input.

To make it work, you must either set it in your controller:

```
$scope.dp_hidden = {};
$scope.dp_hidden = "34.78";
```

OR do the below: 
Note: I have used static values you can try with the expression (harga * (dp/100)) | currency:'':0

```
<input type="text" ng-value="(45 * (34/100)) | currency:'':0" ng-model="dp_hidden">

<td><span id="value-dp" ng-bind="dp_hidden || (45 * (34/100)) | currency:'':0"></span></td>
```